# php form submission error

Tags: php

```
<?php

require ("../Application.php");//session_start(); included in this file
 //init();
 ?>
 <?php
 $_SESSION['message']='';
 echo $_SESSION['key'].":".isset($_POST['submit']).":".$_POST['key'];
 if(isset($_POST['submit']) && ($_SESSION['key'] == $_POST['key'])){
submit();
 }

 function submit(){
echo "submitted";
 }

 ?>
 <?php include("includes/headers.php");?>

 <div class="main">
 <h1>Employee Details</h1>
 <div class="message"><?=$_SESSION['message'];?></div>
 <form name="adduser" action="add.php" method="POST">
 <div class="fileds">
 <div><label for="code">Employe code<i>(6 digit)</i></label></div> <input type="text" name="code" maxlength="6" id="code" />
 </div>


 <div class="fileds">
 <div><label for="fname">First Name</label></div> <input type="text" name="fname" />
 </div>

 <div class="fileds">
 <div><label for="mname">Middle Name</label></div> <input type="text" name="mname" />
 </div>

 <div class="fileds">
 <div><label for="lname">Last Name</label></div> <input type="text" name="lname" />
 <div><label for="father_name">Father's Name</label></div> <input type="text"       name="father_name" />
 <div class="fileds">
 Status: <select name="status" >
 <option value="1">Active</option>
 <option value="0">Inactive</option>
 </select>
 </div>
 <?php
 $key=md5(rand(0,9999999));
 $_SESSION['key']=$key;
 //echo "<br>".$_SESSION['key'];
 ?>
 <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?=$key?>" />
 <br><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="reset" name="clear all" value="clear all" />
 </div>

 </form>
 </div>
 <?php include("includes/footer.php");?>
```

Form is not submitting, dont know what happend. It was working earlier but now.. :(

any please check this, where am wrong????
Edit

Comment: submit() function is not working.. ie the if statment getting wrong.

Comment: submit()? Are you sending this form using JS?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing form action - point it to the script!

Comment: anwyay, you should have a script name there.

Comment: ps: remove reset button, it is not important and you will only confuse users by having it there. use fieldset(s) instead of div(s), be semantically correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<form name="adduser" action="" method="POST">
```

to

```
<form name="adduser" action="<script name>" method="POST">
```

or the name of your script.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to post this form using JavaScript?

If that is the case you should change the name of your submit `input`, because it conflicts with `submit()` method. JS just doesn't know if it should use `input.submit` property or `input.submit()` method.

Change this to something like:

```
<input type="submit" name="mySubmit" value="Save" >
```

and it should start working.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to try

```
$phpself = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
 echo '<form name="adduser" action="$phpself" method="POST">';
```

Though I find this works for me too

Try a last ditch

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($_POST, true)."</pre>";
```

To see what's happen behind the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" onClick="javascript:submit();">
```

And replace your javascript function 'submit()' for this code:

```
function submit(){
     alert("submit!");
     document.forms["adduser"].submit();
}
```